# Programing the android application directory

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I have read many posts explaining about writing android Launchers, but does the launcher include the application directory?

What I am trying to achieve is to customise the screen which displays the installed applications (to launch apps). I wish to exclude displaying certain apps from the grid. Can I achieve this without having to root the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launcher shows the homescreen and the drawer, and is also itself an app. Many third-part launchers exist such as my own, Trebuchet, which can be installed on to your device. However, I hope this is about programming a launcher and not just a general android question.

Comment: Yes @nebkat I am trying to write a custom launcher but the main focus of the launcher is to provide some control over which apps are displayed. Something im preparing for my uni project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The launcher in use is responsible for displaying the app list, and you can omit apps from it if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Launcher is nothing but an app with special characteristics of getting launched on system boot and having being to front on home key.

You do not need root access writing a launcher or excluding any application in the list of apps shown in the launcher. You should be able to achieve it via your business logic.